# What is "antipodenpunkte" (this is German)?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, terminology, geometry

What does "antipodenpunkte" mean?
If you can't find a word about Einstein on the Internet, who should know it?
"In addition, the question arises: can we see stars very close to our antipodenpunkte? These stars should also have a negative parallax. But don't forget that the curvature of space is irregular, so the light travels in a medium filled with viscosity."
--------From "on cosmology and others - letter to Bessel on March 9, 1917" Albert Einstein's "Einstein Essays (Volume I)" from "Einstein Bessel correspondence", pp. 101-103

Comment: From Wiki: "In mathematics, antipodal points of a sphere are those diametrically opposite to each other (the specific qualities of such a definition are that a line drawn from the one to the other passes through the center of the sphere so forms a true diameter). This term applies to opposite points on a circle or any n-sphere"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about language than physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antipode means the direct opposite of something. Antipodenpunkte means the point were something is the direct opposite. Antipodal points in english